# Fitbit for Android, automatically grab user data without OAuth each time I start app

Tags: java, android, json, oauth, fitbit

I have the following code for FitBit integration into Android, it is used from this library https://github.com/manishsri01/FitbitIntegration, I can get the `response.getBody()` to show the JSON body in the webview but I would like the application to be able to automatically update the code without having to login and grab the PIN for OAuth everytime I run the app. What can I do to fix this? I would also like to parse the JSON `.getBody()` into separate string variables. How can I accomplish this?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

OAuthService service;
Token requestToken;
// Replace these with your own api key and secret
private String apiKey = "************************";
private String apiSecret = "*************************";

private String accessToken;
private String tokenSecret;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final WebView wvAuthorize = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvAuthorize);
    final EditText etPIN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPIN);

    service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(FitbitApi.class).apiKey(apiKey)
            .apiSecret(apiSecret).build();

    // network operation shouldn't run on main thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
            final String authURL = service
                    .getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);

            // Webview nagivation should run on main thread again...
            wvAuthorize.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    wvAuthorize.loadUrl(authURL);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();

}

public void btnRetrieveData(View view) {
    EditText etPIN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPIN);
    String gotPIN = etPIN.getText().toString();

    final Verifier v = new Verifier(gotPIN);

    // network operation shouldn't run on main thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, v);

            OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET,
                    "http://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.json");
            service.signRequest(accessToken, request); // the access token from step
            // 4
            final Response response = request.send();
            final TextView tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOutput);

            // Visual output should run on main thread again...
            tvOutput.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tvOutput.setText(response.getBody());
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```

**FitBitApi**

```
public class FitbitApi extends DefaultApi10a {

private static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=%s";

public String getAccessTokenEndpoint() {
    return "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/access_token";
}

public String getRequestTokenEndpoint() {
    return "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token";
}

public String getAuthorizationUrl(Token token) {
    return String.format(AUTHORIZE_URL, token.getToken());
}

}
```

Comment: I checked out their api quickly and I did not see a refresh token endpoint. If you read up on OAuth you'll see that that is another option instead of doing a full auth every time. They may not provide that kind of endpoint this round though. For example, here's google's https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh

Comment: Their API documentation is really really bad I have been trying to figure it out for the last week now

Comment: looks like ill be coming back to this example to show a thorough answer :)

Comment: hi @AndyRoid could you guide me in this a bit. I am able to login with fitbit using Chrome Custom Tab. But now, i want to get/fetch data of user's activity from fitbit. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two separate questions here. Firstly, in regards to saving credentials, there are a number of ways you can do this, the easiest is probably by saving the user/pin details in Android's SharedPreferences. However, you'll still need to make the request for an access token. You should also save the access token (in a cache or DB) and re-use it until it is expired. You may want to read up on ways to secure these credentials if they're considered private.

Your second question regarding parsing JSON is quite common, and if your intention is to map JSON objects to Java objects, you should consider using Google's GSON or Jackson JSON Processor.

If you're intending for Fitbit's API to be a large part of your app, consider using Spring Social and make a Fitbit endpoint (there is a Spring for Android which uses Spring Social). It might be a bit overkill though, but I generally like the structure.

Comment: Can you provide some example code? I have very minimal exp with OAuth and JSON